# Solidty Browser doesn't load properly

Tags: solidity, remix

[Solidity Browser](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/) doesn't load anymore.

Here is a screenshot with the Chrome Developer open.

[image]

on Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m

It's stuck on loading and I see in developer some error messages.
It worked fine just a few minutes ago. Even Internet Explorer fails.

Do you have any idea about what is wrong?

**EDIT:**
I see that in an older [site](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js) it still works

**EDIT2:**
Now even the current version works

**EDIT3:**
After a couple of hours it doesn't work again

**EDIT4:**
It might have been a network issue as I haven't experienced that any more

Comment: I don't think anyone here can really help with that. The best place to bring this up is https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity. It seems to be working now, by the way